# Wrong profile pictures are display for (some) Top Askers on Hot Questions page

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, profile-picture, hot-questions

For some users in the Top Askers section on the [Hot Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) page are wrong profile pictures displayed. Especially for the users that are on top of that list. May be it is a caching problem or that the users have changed their profile picture recently.

[image: Top Askers]

As an **example** use User [Simar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86694/simar).

Picture as Top Asker (Links to his profile on Mathematics)

[image: Asker Picture]

Picture on Profile (Mathematics)

[image: Profile Picture]

The "birdy picture" is used in the profiles on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86694/simar) and [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/users/3059101/simar?tab=accounts). The profiles on [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/2016/simar) and [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/27375/simar) use the identicon.

It seems that the wrong profile picture is used as Top Asker. At least not the picture of the profile that is linked to.

Comment: Is that the picture on **all** their accounts? The accounts on Chemistry and Physics are the identicon.

Comment: @Oded For user Simar at least the "birdy picture" is used on Mathematics and StackExchange. Chemistry and Physics uses the identicon. But the Top Asker links to the Mathematics profile, so i expected to see the bird